# Traversing a difficult List item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data from a list item but can not sort out how can i do it.  I have to select the image src and name of each li.

List is like

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="image.jpg" /></li>
            <li>Image Name</li>
            <li>Image Description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="image-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li>Second Image Name</li>
            <li>Second Image Description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="image-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li>Third Image Name</li>
            <li>Third Image Description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Under what event do you need to get this information? What is the key selector? More details are needed here.

Comment: I have tried selecting but failed. The plan was to loop thorugh each li and then select first to children but can not sort it out.

Comment: from which list are you trying to get the data.where is your JS code part?

Comment: At the page load i have to do the select the required content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("ul li ul").each(function() {
   var $current = $(this),
       imgSrc = $current.find("img").attr("src"),
       name = $current.find("li").eq(1).text();
   // do something with imgSrc and name of current item
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xxYSv/

Comment: Beat me to it good answer. If the ul/li tree is even more complicated than this ~(which wouldn't suprise me with the quality of the question), try using $('ul > li > ul') to make sure you pick the right level.

Comment: Good point @RickDonohoe. Ideally the outer list would have an id or something too.

Comment: I have tried but it says..
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'text'

Comment: Putting an class attribute is possible to the outer li.

Comment: @backTangent - Sorry, my original answer (just before I edited it to add the demo link) used `.get(1)` but should've used `.eq(1)`. Change that part and that error will go away.